# Issue with select SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

Here I'm facing problem with course registration.

I have 3 `tables` named as `dept(dept_id,dept_name)` where `dept_id` is a primary key 2nd table is `semester (semester_id, semester_name,dept_id)` `semester_id` is a primary key and dept_id is a foreign key .3rd table is `courses(c_id,dept_id,sem_id,c_name)` where `c_id` is primary key and `dept_id` and `sem_id` is a foreign key.

I have 3 combo boxes:
 1st regarding department

```
(select* from dept)
<option value="<?php echo $sql_res1["dept_id"]; ?>" <?php if($sql_res1["dept_id"]==$_REQUEST["dept_id"]) { echo "Selected"; } ?>><?php echo $sql_res1["dept_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

2nd combo box is semester :

```
select * from semester where dept_id='$_REQUEST[dept_id]'";
```

3rd combo box is courses.
 I don't know how to query in it. I want that if department is equal to computer science and semester is equal to 1st then 3rd combo box will show their relevant courses same if department is law and semester is equal to 2nd then 3rd combo box shows their relevant courses.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You can fetch it by including `dept_id` and `sem_id` in the where clause.

Comment: " SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `dept_id` = 5 AND `sem_id` = 1; "  // 5 id of department

Comment: Pls show some stuff you already tried & if you get any error in that code? People will not complete your homework over here :(

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showCom(cid) {
        document.frm.submit();
  }</script>
<select name="c_id" id="c_id" onChange="showComp(this.value);">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <?php
        $sql1="SELECT  c.* FROM courses c WHERE c.cat_id='$_REQUEST[cat_id]'";
 $sql_row1=mysql_query($sql1);
       while($sql_res1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row1)){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $sql_res1["c_id"]; ?>" <?php if($sql_res1["c_id"]==$_REQUEST["c_id"]) { echo "Selected"; } ?>><?php echo $sql_res1["c_name"]; ?></option> <?php}?>
 </select>

Comment: kindly give me a solution i'm so worried im very thankfull to you

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this coming to my mind.

---

**Method 1: Asynchronously (AJAX)**

You query the server for the relevant data each time the user changes an option and replace all option entities. For example (jQuery):

```
$("#select-entity-1, #select-entity-2").change(function () {
    var deptId = $("#select-entity-1").val();
    var semId  = $("#select-entity-2").val();
    $.post("path/to/your/script.php", {
            deptId: deptId,
            semId:  semId
        }, function (response) {
            $("#select-entity-3").html(response);
        }
    );
});
```

In PHP it could look something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['deptId']) && isset($_POST['semId'])) {
    $deptId = (int) $_POST['deptId'];
    $semId  = (int) $_POST['semId'];
    $res    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `dept_id` = $deptId AND `sem_id` = $semId");
    if ($res->num_rows) {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['c_id'].'">';
            echo $row['c_name'];
            echo '</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Method 2: Storing and accessing the data via a JavaScript array**

You store the data of the third table in a JavaScript array. It's similar to the asynchonous method, but instead of querying the server you select the relevant data out of the stored array.

---

Which method is more effective highly depends on the size of the third table. When working with a big set of data, the asynchronous method would most likely be the better choice. Otherwise, I'd tend to the second one, as it has no delay and you usually want to avoid unnecessary traffic.

As you didn't provide any code, this is all I can provide you with. I hope it'll lead you to the right direction.

Comment: what is entity 1 and entity 2  kindly brief

Comment: kindly brief i'm a fresh student and i have to done this because i submitted my project after few days kindly brief

Comment: Obviously, entity 1, 2 and 3 are to be replaced with the ids of your select boxes. You basically want to put an event listener on the first two select boxes which fires everytime a user changes the option. Then you replace the third select box with the relevant options.

Comment: here is my code 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> function showCom(cid) { document.frm.submit(); }</script> <select name="c_id" id="c_id" onChange="showComp(this.value);"> <option value="">--Select--</option> <?php $sql1="SELECT c.* FROM courses c WHERE c.cat_id='$_REQUEST[cat_id]'"; $sql_row1=mysql_query($sql1); while($sql_res1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row1)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $sql_res1["c_id"]; ?>" <?php if($sql_res1["c_id"]==$_REQUEST["c_id"]) { echo "Selected"; } ?>><?php echo $sql_res1["c_name"]; ?></option> <?php}?> </select>

Comment: Dude, honestly, this is not a "I will do your homework" platform... at least TRY to do it yourself. That's is actually the point of studying it.

Comment: i do many time but all in vein kindly help me i have to submit my project on monday

Comment: We won't hand you over the full project. I gave you all the information you need, even with an example. And as long you don't even put efforts into editing your original post and providing the broken code in a readable way, nobody will waste their time guessing what you want. At least give us the feeling that you're actually trying.